# get the forignkey value in django form

Tags: python, django

I have created a forms.py,model.py and views.py as follows.

## One table in Model.py

```
 class Billing_Detail(models.Model):
       bill_choices = [('Permanent','Permanent'),('Temporary','Temporary')]
       emp_name = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
       emp_proj = models.ForeignKey(Project)
       bill_type = models.CharField(max_length = 10,choices=bill_choices,verbose_name='Bill type')
       start_date = models.DateField(blank=True,verbose_name='Billing Start Date',null=True)
       end_date = models.DateField(blank=True,verbose_name='Billing End Date',null=True)
```

## forms.py

```
  class AddBillingForm(forms.Form):
            emp_list = Employee.objects.filter()
            proj_list = Project.objects.filter()
            bill_type = ['Permanent','Temporary']
            Employee = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Employee.objects.all())
            Project =  forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Project.objects.all())
            #Sub_Project = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_my_choices())
            Sub_Project =  forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Sub_Project.objects.all())
            Billing_Type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=zip(bill_type,bill_type))
            Billing_Start_Date = forms.DateField
            Billing_End_Date = forms.DateField
```

## views.py

```
  def addbilling(request):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            form = AddBillingForm()
        else:
            #A POST request
            form = AddBillingForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                print "inside"
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                print post
                employee = form.cleaned_data['Employee']
                print employee
                return HttpResponse('thanks')

        return render(request, 'addbilling.html', {'form': form,})
```

In above all works fine. Except When i submit the form. It validate it then gives me the values in form.cleaned_data['Employee']. However it gives me the name. But i need to ID of that name so that i can insert into the db properlly

Comment: Actually, you will get an `Employee` object not just name. You can use it directly as is.

Comment: Employee is a ModelChoiceField so it should be returning the item itself. Thw reason you are seeing the name is when you print a django object it tries to print a 'nice' version not the id. What happens when you try and save the Employee to the db?

Comment: I have changed to ModelForm. If i save directly it works. Here if i want to customize the form . Like according to project subproject should map. Where should i add the ajax and jquery? or is there any inbuilt way to achieve this.